# Node.js (Express) Dynamically Inserting Meta Tags Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, create-react-app, meta-tags

My React website served using Express from the back works with:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build')));
```

That said, I'm refactoring the backend code such that each route adds dynamic meta tags and serves up the website separately with this:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const pathToIndex = path.resolve(__dirname, './client/build', 'index.html');

  try {
    // try dynamically inserting title meta tag
    fs.readFile(pathToIndex, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      data = data.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, "ABC");
      res.send(data);
    });
  } catch(err) {
    res.sendFile(pathToIndex);
  }
});
```

The above refactor causes the following error:

[image]

Here's my folder structure:

[image]

Any clue what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const pathToIndex = path.resolve(__dirname, ".", "index.html");

  const fileData = fs.readFileSync(pathToIndex, { encoding: "utf8" });

  // data = fileData.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, "ABC");
  data = fileData.replace(/App/g, "ABC");

  console.log(data);

  return res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work; similar issue occurred.

Comment: Sorry there was a sily mistake by me readFileSync does not expect a call back. so changing my answer above. I tried it and not giving any error to me. may be the issue is in your index.html file.